# Strange output for lb instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data 
 number:.word 3222
.text 
.globl _start
 _start:
      li $v0,1
      la $t0,number
      lb $a0,($t0)
      syscall
      li $v0,10
      syscall
```

I am totally new to MIPS Assembly Language. I was trying to get the first digit of Label.word 3222, which is 3. But the output is 150. I am just curious where does this 150 come from and how could I get the value I want (get second and third digits as well)

Comment: Hint: 3222 is 0xc96.

Comment: ... and 0x96 is ...

Comment: Thank you so much. But I still don't understand why I get the decimal value for 0x96 @WeatherVane

Comment: 3222 is 0x0c96. But, MIPS is _little-endian_ so this is being stored as [the equivalent of] `.byte 0x96,0x0c`

Comment: Oh I have no clue with MIPS but I guess `lb` is a byte load from the first byte of your word storage in littleendian format so `0x96` == `150` is output.

Comment: @StewieGriffin re your comment: I don't understand if you are asking why you get a ***decimal*** value, or asking why you get the decimal value of ***`0x96`***.

Answer (score 2):

`word` is 32 bit value. MIPS can be set to both big or little endianness.

If you will learn what is the most common way how to encode integer values into bits, using binary representation, you will see that single byte (8 bits) can contain values from 0 to 255.

32 bits = 4 bytes can thus contain 256<sup>4</sup> values: `0` - `4294967295`.

So `3222` in binary is `0000 1100 1001 0110` (16 bits only to save me from writing another 16 zeroes for upper 16 bits).

Your target MIPS platform is set to little-endian mode, ie. the first byte contains the 8 least significant bits, so in memory that number is encoded as bits:

```
address: |   value:
+0       |  1001 0110   (in hexa 0x96, or decimal 150)
+1       |  0000 1100   (0x0C, 12)
+2       |  0000 0000   (0x00, 0)
+3       |  0000 0000   (0x00, 0)
```

And the total value is 150 * 256<sup>0</sup> + 12 * 256<sup>1</sup> + 0 * 256<sup>2</sup> + 0 * 256<sup>3</sup> = 3222.

To get first digit of that number, you either have to calculate log<sub>10</sub> of it to know which 10th power is first, or proceed from the right by first calculating div/mod pair of 10<sup>1</sup>, the remainder is the "ones" digit, and quotient can be used for another division by 10 to get "tens", then "hundreds", etc.. until you get zero.

Overall note how base-10 (decimal) numbers are very cumbersome for computer and require lot of actual calculation to figure out particular digits (unless you store them as string or in some other than binary encoding (BCD for example) -> then it is easy to get particular digit, but instead you can NOT use simple arithmetic instructions like `add` over them, because those understand the binary representation).

Also note how group of 4 bits form values from 0 to 15, which does exactly 1:1 match hexadecimal digits 0-F, so from hexadecimal representation of value you can easily read values of particular bytes (two digits = one byte). `3222 = 0x00000C96 = four bytes 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C and 0x96` (stored in memory in little-endian order, ie. reversed starting with `0x96`).

To particular details of dec <-> hex <-> binary <-> octal conversions, and why/how it works just refer to wikipedia or some tutorials.

Just one short advice: the `3222` is not number `3222`, it's the representation of number `3222` in base-10 (decimal) formatting, which is commonly used by humans. But the value itself doesn't have any formatting, it's purely abstract thing. By writing it down as `3222` or saying it as sounds, or using other (hexa/binary) encoding you are producing just "image" of the real mathematical value, actually damaging it's attributes by any imperfections which your desired representation has. Like for example in decimal formatting every integer has two ways to be represented, one common short `3222`, and the other with infinite series of nines fractions `3221.9999...` (it's the same number).

Various computer encoding of values (especially floating point ones) have their own limitations and quirks, so you should learn how computer encode values to understand what you are using in your calculations. So you will be not surprised later by a fact, that in C++ on x86_64 for example: `(1e40 + 1.0 == 1e40)` is true.

Comment: And in your code you fetch by `lb` only the first byte of the value (`0x96`), from the +0 address.

Comment: Yes, and the hexadecimal representation is no coincidence. It is a convenient way for humans to understand a binary value: by grouping bits (binary digits) in sets of 4.

Comment: Now I realized there's actually no way to represent `0` as the 9-fractions infinite series in decimal formatting... wow... :D ... so much for using words like "every" or "all"... :D

Comment: @Ped7g Well to be correct it is "every non-zero rational" (e.g. 3.14 and 3.13999... represent the same number) :D